# How to run a google script from a google doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have copied a script to remove empty paragraphs from a google doc & I can run it from the script editor. It says in the script it will operate on the active document but I don't know what that is and don't want to just run it without knowing what doc it will execute on if any. How can I run this from the currently selected document? Is this possible?

Comment: active document = currently selected document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can use a script (follow the links to read up on these things):

1. If you open the script editor from the document it means that your script is attached to that document and it's called ["container-bound"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
2. If you create a standalone script file in https://script.google.com/home (or just your Google Drive) then there is no such thing as `ActiveDocument` as it's not container-bound.

You can use [openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)) or [openByURL()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openByUrl(String)) to specify a document that you have access to, however, you need to specify an ID or URL (the ID is the last string in the URL) so the script cannot take a random document and edit it unless it accesses your Google Drive data and looks for a file by name. If it works just with the Google Doc it will not need access to your Google Drive and before you run the script it will request access to different things just like in Android.